# Can a function be inside another function?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a library project but my function called `changeColor` inside the `readStatus` function does not appear to be working.

I've tried separating it but having two event listeners on the same button does not appear to work. My goal is for `readStatus` function to allow a user to update the status of a book from no to yes when finished with the book.

Likewise, I want to change the background color of the div (class: card) when yes to be green and no to be red.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```js
let myLibrary = [];

function Book(title, author, pages, read) {
  this.title = title;
  this.author = author;
  this.pages = pages;
  this.read = read;
}

function addBookToLibrary(title, author, pages, read) {
  let book = new Book(title, author, pages, read);
  myLibrary.push(book);
  displayOnPage();
}

function displayOnPage() {
  const books = document.querySelector(".books");

  const removeDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
  for (let i = 0; i < removeDivs.length; i++) {
    removeDivs[i].remove();
  }

  let index = 0;
  myLibrary.forEach((myLibrarys) => {
    let card = document.createElement("div");
    card.classList.add("card");
    books.appendChild(card);

    for (let key in myLibrarys) {
      let para = document.createElement("p");
      para.textContent = `${key}: ${myLibrarys[key]}`;
      card.appendChild(para);
    }

    let read_button = document.createElement("button");
    read_button.classList.add("read_button");
    read_button.textContent = "Read ";
    read_button.dataset.linkedArray = index;
    card.appendChild(read_button);

    read_button.addEventListener("click", readStatus);

    let delete_button = document.createElement("button");
    delete_button.classList.add("delete_button");
    delete_button.textContent = "Remove";
    delete_button.dataset.linkedArray = index;
    card.appendChild(delete_button);

    delete_button.addEventListener("click", removeFromLibrary);

    function removeFromLibrary() {
      let retrieveBookToRemove = delete_button.dataset.linkedArray;
      myLibrary.splice(parseInt(retrieveBookToRemove), 1);
      card.remove();
      displayOnPage();
    }

    function readStatus() {
      let retrieveBookToToggle = read_button.dataset.linkedArray;
      Book.prototype = Object.create(Book.prototype);
      const toggleBook = new Book();

      if (myLibrary[parseInt(retrieveBookToToggle)].read == "yes") {
        toggleBook.read = "no";
        myLibrary[parseInt(retrieveBookToToggle)].read = toggleBook.read;
      } else if (myLibrary[parseInt(retrieveBookToToggle)].read == "no") {
        toggleBook.read = "yes";
        myLibrary[parseInt(retrieveBookToToggle)].read = toggleBook.read;
      }

      let colorDiv = document.querySelector(".card");

      function changeColor() {
        for (let i = 0; i < length.myLibrary; i++) {
          if (myLibrary[i].read == "yes") {
            colorDiv.style.backgroundColor = "green";
          } else if (myLibrary[i].read == "no") {
            colorDiv.style.backgroundColor = "red";
          }
        }
      }

      displayOnPage();
    }

    index++;
  });
}

let add_book = document.querySelector(".add-book");
add_book.addEventListener("click", popUpForm);

function popUpForm() {
  document.getElementById("data-form").style.display = "block";
}

function closeForm() {
  document.getElementById("data-form").style.display = "none";
}

let close_form_button = document.querySelector("#close-form");
close_form_button.addEventListener("click", closeForm);

function intakeFormData() {
  let title = document.getElementById("title").value;
  let author = document.getElementById("author").value;
  let pages = document.getElementById("pages").value;
  let read = document.getElementById("read").value;

  if (title == "" || author == "" || pages == "" || read == "") {
    return;
  }

  addBookToLibrary(title, author, pages, read);

  document.getElementById("data-form").reset();
}

let submit_form = document.querySelector("#submit-form");

submit_form.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  intakeFormData();
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: rgb(245, 227, 205);
}

.books {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px;
    gap: 10px;
}

.card {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.forms {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

form {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

select,
input[type="text"],
input[type="number"] {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.buttons-container {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.buttons-container button {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 2px;
}

.add-book {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#data-form {
    display: none;
}

.read_button {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="forms">
            <button class="add-book">Add Book To Library</button>
            <div class="pop-up">
                <form id="data-form">
                    <div class="form-container">
                        <label for="title">Title</label>
                        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-container">
                        <label for="author">Author</label>
                        <input type="text" name="author" id="author" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-container">
                        <label for="pages">Pages</label>
                        <input type="number" name="pages" id="pages" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-container">
                        <label for="read">Read</label>
                        <select name="read" id="read">
                            <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                            <option value="no">No</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="buttons-container">
                        <button type="submit" id="submit-form">Submit Form</button>
                        <button type="button" id="close-form">Close Form</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="books"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The `changeColor()` function is not being called.

Comment: There are multiple problems.  changeColor() is never called.  Yet, even if you were to call it, the loop will not work because length is not set.

Comment: Do you need to declare the `changeColor()` function every time you click?

Comment: I missed that, I called changecolor() under the displayOnPage(), I tried myLibrary.length instead but it does not appear to work.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things needed.

First, you should put the `readStatus` and `removeFromLibrary` functions outside of the `foreach` loop.

Then I think you are wanting `changeColor` to run whenever `readStatus` is run. Either put the `changeColor` code directly inside the `readStatus` or put `changeColor()` inside `readStatus`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the Book to not be a function but a class.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).